# How do I convert a PowerPoint file to PDF using Aspose 6.4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspose

I am using `aspose.slides.dll` v6.4.0 to convert `.pptx` files to `.pdf`.

My Code:

```
public static MemoryStream pptx2Pdf(byte[] FileRead)
{
    MemoryStream ResultStream = new MemoryStream();
    Aspose.Slides.Pptx.PresentationEx pres = new Aspose.Slides.Pptx.PresentationEx(new MemoryStream(FileRead));
    pres.Save(ResultStream, Aspose.Slides.Export.SaveFormat.Pdf);
    return ResultStream;
}
```

But when the method is called, the following exception is shown and file is not converted:

> Attempt by security transparent method 'ns3.Class115.smethod_6(System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData, Boolean)' to access security critical method 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(IntPtr, Byte[], Int32, Int32)' failed.
>
> Assembly 'Aspose.Slides, Version=6.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.

I tried to search for details about this exception, but could find nothing relevant to it. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: We are heavy users of Aspose, but never had that issue. Did you ask in the Aspose Forum? They are normally pretty good at responding.

Comment: Ok i will ask in aspose forum..

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet seems fine and also you are using Aspose.Slides for .NET 6.4.0. I would suggest you to please try using [Aspose.Slides for .NET 6.6.0](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/default.aspx) which is at the moment the latest available version. I am hopeful that the new version will work. Even if there is an issue then please share the sample presentation with us on Aspose.Slides forum. We will be obliged to help you.